# Rails: Retrieve value from hash in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There's a good number of related questions but their answers haven't helped me. I have a method `fetch_all_sections` which populates an array with this line:

```
all_sections << {:id => section.id, :sortlabel => section.sortlabel, :title => section.title, :depth => depth}
```

In a loop in a view, I would like to easily access the values by their key, like this:

```
<% fetch_all_sections(@standard).each do |section| %>
  <%= section.id %>
<% end %>
```

This says no method id on section. `section[:id]` and `#{section['id']}` have similarly themed errors. I used a hash for ease of retrieval - should I use a different structure?

I'm hoping I don't need .map like `section.map { |id| id[:id] }` for every value.

EDIT: Here's the context. It's a little loopy (pun intended) but it does what's intended.

```
# Calls itself for each section recursively to fetch all possible children
def fetch_all_sections(standard, section = nil, depth = 0)
  all_sections = []

  if section.nil?
    rootsections = standard.sections.sorted
    if ! rootsections.nil?
      rootsections.each_with_index do |section, i|
        depth = section.sortlabel.split('.').length - 1
        all_sections.push(fetch_all_sections(standard, section, depth))
      end
    end
  else

    all_sections << {:id => section.id, :sortlabel => section.sortlabel, :title => section.title, :depth => depth}

    section.children.sorted.each do |section|
      all_sections | fetch_all_sections(standard, section)
    end
  end

  return all_sections
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following:

```
<% fetch_all_sections(@standard).each do |section| %>
  <%= section['id'] %>
<% end %>
```

If not working, try debugging using these methods:

```
<% fetch_all_sections(@standard).each do |section| %>
  <%= section.inspect %>
  <%= section.class %>
<% end %>
```

As the Question author said, this fixed:

```
all_sections << fetch_all_sections(standard, section, depth).first
```

And tell us the output of the inspect

Comment: It indeed seems that I've made an array of arrays with 1 hash that has multiple key, value pairs. This works `section[0][:id]`. flatten apparently doesn't affect it.

Comment: Can you post the code of your `fech_all_sections` method please @Archonic?

Comment: Perhaps since the method calls itself, the array initializer is being pushed.. to itself? Inception! But `all_sections = [] if all_sections.nil?` changed nothing.

Comment: `fetch_all_sections` returns an array and you push the result of `fetch_all_sections` into another Array. You have a bi-dimensionnal Array here, you need to `flatten` it after your push.

Comment: `flatten` unfortunately doesn't remove sub-arrays if each element is by itself an array. `[[1],[2],[3]].flatten` #=> `[[1],[2],[3]]`

Comment: Got it! Just needed the `.first` method. `all_sections << fetch_all_sections(standard, section, depth).first` since, like you said, I was returning an array which was being pushed into itself.

Comment: That's weird, Ruby 1.9.3: `[[1],[2],[3]].flatten #=> [1, 2, 3]`

Comment: Oh, just tried it in the console and 1.9.2 is getting `[1, 2, 3]`. But when used in my helper method after pushing and just before the return, it was `[[1],[2],[3]]`. Various combinations had no effect. Is the flatten method initialized after helper methods?